# Certain files are "Outside of project"

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

[image: https://i.imgur.com/OoieutJ.png]

On my project it seems files are periodically appearing like this. They seem to be excluded but are actually in my project. The problem with this is they get aren't getting any linting or other benefits.

I know you can exclude folders and whatnot but i've no idea how these files are ending up outside the project.

For example when i try to Refactor -> Rename:
[image]

Any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that these files/folders aren't added as a library in Settings | Languages&Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries.

Also please provide a screenshot of Settings | Directories.